# azure startup task not logging or firing

Tags: batch-file, azure, task, startup

based on this article:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks/
I created version.bat which logs the version number to startuplog.txt. 
But I don't see any .txt file from my run after downloading all the files using ftp for search purposes.  I do see version.bat the file I created in wwwroot and wwwroot\bin.

my version.bat looks like this:

ECHO The current version is %MyVersionNumber% >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt"     2>&1

EXIT /B 0

Any ideas what might be causing this?
ServiceDefinition.csdef

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="MyRESTService.Azure"    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition"   schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
<WebRole name="MyRESTService" vmsize="Small">
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine ="version.bat" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
  <Task commandLine="installvcredst.bat" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
</Startup>
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
</Endpoints>
</WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: Can you post the startup task configuration from your CSDEF file?

Comment: Is there any evidence of it running in the Windows Azure event log?

Comment: No mention of .bat anything in eventlog.xml in the LogFIles directory

Comment: You did not mention if Copy to Output Directory property for your startup batch file is set to Copy Always. Is it?

Comment: yes it is for both batch files called and both batch files are on the ftp remote directory.  So they made it up there.  But still no evidence of them running and nothing in the windows azure event log for today at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see evidence of it being called in the Windows Azure log, then I would be more explicit with the path to batch file.  I believe the working directory for the process which runs the startup tasks is the bin directory, so if your batch file is in the root, specify it as ..\version.bat.

[image]